# node-canvas font not applied to the text

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, html5-canvas, node-canvas

```
const { createCanvas, loadImage, registerFont } = require('canvas');
const fs = require('fs');

const myfact = "when a person dies, they have 7 minutes of brain activity left."
const settings = {
  txtarea: {
    x: 540,
    y: 0,
    width: 864,
    height: 1080
  },
  font: 'Quote',
  lineHeight: 1,
  minFontSize: 50,
  maxFontSize: 70
};

async function generateImage() {
  const canvas = createCanvas(1080, 1080);
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  const bgimage = await loadImage("./background.jpg");
  context.drawImage(bgimage, 0, 0, 1080, 1080);

  registerFont('./Quote.ttf', { family: 'Quote', Style: 'Regular' });
  
  context.textAlign = 'center';
  context.textBaseline = 'middle';
  context.fillStyle = '#fff';

  drawMultiLineFact(context, myfact, settings);

  const buffer = canvas.toBuffer('image/png');
  fs.writeFileSync('./image.png', buffer);
};

function drawMultiLineFact(context, myfact, settings) {
  const words = require('words-array')(myfact);
  var lines = [];
  let y;
  let lastFittingLines;
  let lastFittingFont;
  let lastFittingY;
  let lastFittingLineHeight;
  
  for (var fontSize = settings.minFontSize; fontSize <= settings.maxFontSize; fontSize++) {
    var lineHeight = fontSize * settings.lineHeight;
    context.font = `'` + fontSize + `px "Quote"'`
    var x = settings.txtarea.x;
    y = lineHeight;
    lines = []
    var line = ''

    for (var word of words) {
      var linePlus = line + word + ' '
      if (context.measureText(linePlus).width > (settings.txtarea.width)) {
        lines.push({ text: line, x: x, y: y });
        line = word + ' '
        y += lineHeight
      } else {
        line = linePlus
      };
    };
    lines.push({ text: line, x: x, y: y });
    if (y > settings.txtarea.height) break;
    lastFittingLines = lines;
    lastFittingFont = context.font;
    lastFittingY = y;
    lastFittingLineHeight = lineHeight;
  };
  lines = lastFittingLines;
  context.font = lastFittingFont;
  const offset = settings.txtarea.y - lastFittingLineHeight / 2 + (settings.txtarea.height - lastFittingY) / 2;
  for (var line of lines) {
    context.fillText(line.text.trim(), line.x, line.y + offset);
  };
};

generateImage();
```

I am using the above code to write text but the font i am using is not applied to the text.

I think there is problem in registering font.

file

index.js
quote.js

both in same root folder.

and idk why they say your code is mostly the code . i written so so so may thing lol egnore this paragraph.

and idk why they say your code is mostly the code . i written so so so may thing lol egnore this paragraph.

and idk why they say your code is mostly the code . i written so so so may thing lol egnore this paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [project's Readme](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas#registerfont):

> `registerFont()`
>
> ```
> registerFont(path: string, { family: string, weight?: string, style?: string }) => void
> ```
>
> To use a font file that is not installed as a system font, use
> registerFont() to register the font with Canvas. *This must be done
> before the Canvas is created.*

(emphasize not mine)

You must call it **before** you create your canvas.

Then, your font declaration is broken. There are `'` single quotes that shouldn't be there.
Change it simply

```js
context.font = fontSize + `px Quote`
```